# How to unpack/unzip a zip archive on google cloud data flow using apache beam apk

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, zip

I have a zip archive with further nested zip archives, I need to unpack the parent zip archive on google cloud dataflow using apache beam apk and store then resultant files in google cloud storage.

This is for a variable size input file where the size might vary from 1GB to 100GB. and google data flow looks like a promising candidate for the job.

```
expected input:
-MyFiles.zip
   -MyNestedFiles-folder(1)
        -MyMoreNestedFiles.zip  
        -Other_non_zips
   -MyNestedFiles-folder(n)
        -MyMoreNestedFiles.zip  
        -Other_non_zips
   -Other_non_zips


expected output:
   -MyNestedFiles-folder(1)
        -MyMoreNestedFiles.zip  
        -Other_non_zips
   -MyNestedFiles-folder(n)
        -MyMoreNestedFiles.zip  
        -Other_non_zips
   -Other_non_zips
```

Comment: Are you saving the input zip file locally or somewhere else?

Comment: I'm saving the input zip file in cloud storage. The input and output buckets are different, however that shouldn't be a problem.